# Dropdown does not closing for first time?

Tags: javascript, html, css, drop-down-menu, firebase-authentication

I have login button on header. when user login successful, it will display user name instead of login on header(Note: user name are retrieved from firebase database). When tapping user name, it drop downs with option account and logout.

My issue drop down open when tapping on user name but tapping on user name it does not closing drop down options. and caret button does showing on right.

Here is the output screen 
[image]

here is my code script.js.

### In script.js i'm getting user name and appending into header.

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
    if (user) {
        // User is signed in.
        auth = user;
        var uid = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
        console.log(uid);
        $('body').removeClass('auth-false').addClass('auth-true');
        db.collection("users").doc(uid)
            .onSnapshot(function(doc) {
                console.log("Current data: ", doc.data());
                var name = doc.data().name
                $('.user-info').append('<span class="user-name">' + name + '</span>');
                console.log(name);
            });
    } else {
        // User is signed out.

        $('body').removeClass('auth-true').addClass('auth-false');
        auth && contactsRef.child(auth.uid).off('child_added', onChildAdd);
        $('#contacts').html('');
        auth = null;
    }
});
```

### here is my header code:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" >
    <!-- <li class="active" ><a href="#" style="color: #4F5459; font-size: 18px; font-weight: 600">What We Do <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li> -->
    <li>
        <a href="#" style="color: #4F5459; font-size: 18px; font-weight: 600">What We Do</a>
    </li>

    <li>
        <a href="#" style="color: #4F5459; font-size: 18px; font-weight: 600">Savings Process</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#" style="color: #4F5459; font-size: 18px; font-weight: 600">Tech</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#" style="color: #4F5459; font-size: 18px; font-weight: 600">Pricing</a>
    </li>

    <!-- <li><button type="button" class="btn navbar-btn  userAuth unauthenticated" style="color: #4F5459; font-size: 18px; font-weight: 600; background-color: #ffffff00; outline: 0; box-shadow: none!important;" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#registerModal">Register</button></li> -->
    <li>
        <button type="button" class="btn navbar-btn  userAuth unauthenticated" style="color: #4F5459; font-size: 18px; font-weight: 600; background-color: #ffffff00; outline: 0; box-shadow: none!important;" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#loginModal">Login</button>
    </li>

    <button class="btn  navbar-btn userAuth unauthenticated" style="background-color: #71D72C; color: #4F5459; font-size: 18px;">Free Trail</button>

    <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" id="options" class="dropdown-toggle userAuth authenticated user-info" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" style="color: #71D72C; font-size: 18px; font-weight: 600" alt="User">
            <span class="caret"/>
        </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li>
                <button type="button" class="btn navbar-btn userAuth authenticated" id="logout"   >Logout</button>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Another action</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Something else here</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: can you provide a jsfiddle?

Comment: Please click [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55334488/edit) and then `[<>]` to create a [mcve]

Comment: @HagaiWild ok sure

Comment: @HagaiWild jsfiddle does not shows proper output..

Comment: have you added firebase cdn?

Comment: try  $('.user-info').click(function(e){$('.dropdown-menu').toggle()})

Comment: @HagaiWild added

Comment: Might I ask where?